# googlecharts php postgresql timestamp format datetime axis cleaner

Tags: postgresql, format, timestamp, axis, pygooglechart

I got my application barebones up and running, but the date formatting on the bottom axis is horrible.
https://s28.postimg.org/fts5h6fel/app.jpg

here is my goal for the bottom axis formatting:
https://s28.postimg.org/57qwu5y3x/app2.jpg

is there a way to use the timestamp from postgresql as a datetime in googlecharts?

currently my script imports the timestamp field as string or it does not work at all.

postgresql db table:

    `CREATE TABLE stats(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, spo INTEGER NOT NULL, hr INTEGER NOT NULL, spt timestamp NOT NULL);`

example data:

    `patient=# SELECT * FROM stats LIMIT 100;
     id  | spo | hr |            spt
    -----+-----+----+----------------------------
       1 |  97 | 80 | 2017-01-01 22:39:48.606672
       2 |  96 | 79 | 2017-01-01 22:39:49.60654
       3 |  97 | 79 | 2017-01-01 22:39:50.606504
       4 |  96 | 79 | 2017-01-01 22:39:51.60639
       5 |  96 | 76 | 2017-01-01 22:39:52.606374
       6 |  96 | 74 | 2017-01-01 22:39:53.606271
       7 |  96 | 72 | 2017-01-01 22:39:54.606251
       8 |  96 | 71 | 2017-01-01 22:39:55.606124
       9 |  97 | 70 | 2017-01-01 22:39:56.606061
      10 |  97 | 69 | 2017-01-01 22:39:57.606012`

here is my current webpage:

```
<?php
    $con = pg_connect("host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=patient user=spo password=secretpass") or die("db connection failed!");
    $sth = pg_query($con, "select spt,spo,hr from stats");
    $table = array();
    $table[] = ["spt", "spo", "hr"];
    while($r = pg_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
        $table[] = [(string) $r['spt'], (int) $r['spo'], (int) $r['hr']];
    }
    $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
    echo $jsonTable;
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);
            var options = {
                title: 'spO2/hr monitor',
                legend: { position: 'bottom' }
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 1200px; height: 720px"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**if this answer helps you solve a problem your working on, please upvote this post, im new to this site.**

got it working: https://s28.postimg.org/6hwya5925/done.jpg

I ended up using unix timestamps in the DB and used that as the primary key as well, anywhere that i needed to modify the timestamp I used string manipulation when necessary.

new postgresql database details:

```
CREATE TABLE stats(utc INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, spo INTEGER NOT NULL, hr INTEGER NOT NULL);

patient=# SELECT * FROM stats LIMIT 10;
    utc     | spo | hr
------------+-----+----
 1464499543 |  89 | 63
 1464499544 |  89 | 64
 1464499545 |  89 | 65
 1464499546 |  89 | 65
 1464499547 |  89 | 66
 1464499548 |  89 | 65
 1464499549 |  89 | 65
 1464499550 |  89 | 65
 1464499551 |  89 | 65
 1464499552 |  89 | 65
```

index.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.structure.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.theme.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
        $(function() {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
            $("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd").datepicker("setDate", "-1");
            $("#datepicker").datepicker().on("change", function (e) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'getChart.php',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {dtpickerdate: $(this).val()},
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (result) {
                        $("#chart").html(result);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'getChart.php',
                type: 'GET',
                data: {dtpickerdate: $("#datepicker").val()},
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#chart").html(result);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"><br>
        <div id="chart" style="width: 100%; height: 97%"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

getChart.php:

```
<?php
    $dtpickerdate = isset($_GET['dtpickerdate']) ? $_GET['dtpickerdate'] : "2016-06-06";
    $con = pg_connect("dbname=patient user=spo password=secretpass") or die("db connection failed!");
    $d1 = (string)strtotime($dtpickerdate.' 12:00:00');
    $nday = (int)substr($dtpickerdate, -2) + 1;
    $ndat = substr($dtpickerdate, 0, 8).(string)$nday;
    $d2 = (string)strtotime($ndat.' 12:00:00');
    $sth = pg_query($con, "select * from stats where utc between ".$d1." and ".$d2);
    $table['cols'] = array(
        array(id => 'utc', label => 'Time', type => 'datetime'),
        array(id => 'spo', label => 'spO2', type => 'number'),
        array(id => 'hr', label => 'PulseRate', type => 'number')
    );
    while($r = pg_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
        $temp = array();
        $mon = (int)date("m", $r['utc']) - 1;
        $mdat = "Date(".date("Y, ", $r['utc']).(string)$mon.date(", d, H, i, s)", $r['utc']);
        $temp[] = array(v => (string) $mdat);
        $temp[] = array(v => (int) $r['spo']);
        $temp[] = array(v => (int) $r['hr']);
        $rows[] = array(c => $temp);
    }
    $table['rows'] = $rows;
    $json = json_encode($table);
    //echo $json;
?>

<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$json?>);
      var options = {
                    chartArea: {'width': '92%', 'height': '86%'},
                    title: 'spO2/hr monitor',
                    legend: { position: 'bottom' },
                    vAxis: {viewWindow:{max:100, min:50}, gridlines:{count:6}, minorGridlines:{count:4}},
                    hAxis: {
                        gridlines: {
                            count: -1,
                            units: {
                                days: {format: ['MMM dd']},
                                hours: {format: ['HH:mm', 'ha']},
                            }
                        },
                        minorGridlines: {
                            units: {
                                hours: {format: ['hh:mm:ss a', 'ha']},
                                minutes: {format: ['HH:mm a Z', ':mm']}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: google charts works but is honestly just too slow for the number of data points in my data set, I am in the process of switching over to dygraph